# Ruby on Rails roles for Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, authorization

I have a following problem. I'm writing authorization from scratch with [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTNGtpfxPtg). But in this tutorial user role has boolean type. I my model user_role has string type. I want to make that, if you have `user_role == 'admin'` you can access everywhere. If you have `user_role == 'user'` you can just access only to action show and index.

I have added to the model following code file name:

permission.rb

```
class Permission < Struct.new(:user)

  def allow?(controller, action)
    if user.user_role == "user"
    controller == "posts" && action.in? == (%w[index show])
  elsif user.user_role == "admin"
      true
    end
  end
end
```

and when i click edit in my page that gives me error :

> NoMethodError in PostsController#edit undefined method `user_role' for
>   nil:NilClass

How can I solve it ?

Part of my model

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.boolean "read"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.date "creation_date"
    t.string "author"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "user_role"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

My aplication Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authorize, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy, :update ]

#  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
#    app_dashboard_index_path
#end
private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end


def current_permission
  @current_permission ||= Permission.new(current_user)
end

def authorize
  if !current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
    redirect_to posts_path, alert: "Not authorized"
  end
end
```

MY Post Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy, :update ]


  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def new
    @post =  current_user.posts.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Data has hanged"
      redirect_to post_path
    else
      render action 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end

private

def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :read, :author)
end


end
```

(Previous I had tried write authorization with gem CanCanCan and Pundit,but I didn't understand how it works, so I delete them from project).

Answer (score 0):

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#edit undefined method `user_role' for nil:NilClass
```

This means you are trying to call 'user_role' on an object, and that object is nil when it shouldn't be. I'm guessing in your Permission class it has not had user defined. Either way I'd approach it in a different way:

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authorize, skip: [:show, :index]

  def authorize
    return if current_user && current_user.user_role == 'admin'
    redirect_to posts_path, alert: 'You are not allowed to access this part of the site'
  end
end
```

This will call the authorize method in every action of the posts controller apart from show and index.

If a user is logged in and their user_role is 'admin', the method will return and do nothing. Otherwise it will redirect to the posts path.